# Return to append on previous line after a command in a bash script

Tags: bash, curl, echo

I'm using echo to output text and curl to get my ip from a website:

```
echo -n "IP: "; curl ifconfig.co/x-real-ip; echo -e "\b test"
```

what I noticed is that when the curl command is executed it automatically changes to a new line, and with the escape \b i thought maybe i could backspace to the previous line and output some more text there. Though that is not working apparently. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `echo "IP: \`curl other args\` test"`

Comment: this outputs everything in the " " as a string.. no command is executed among those.

Comment: impossible. back tick will be substituted inside of double quotes. what environment are you running bash in?

Comment: Replace `ifconfig.co/x-real-ip` by `network-science.de/tools/myip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the line is incremented, echoing a backspace will not help. Try this:

```
printf "IP: $(curl -s ifconfig.co/x-real-ip) anything-else\n"
```

Comment: xargs used on curl returns the whole process and info of obtaining the information through the internet, download/upload speed, total size, received! thanks though for the quick answer!

Comment: @quelotic: second try please :)

Comment: same thing happens, feels strange cause all the download info of the curl is showing right before the printf starts printing... the lines print correctly on my screen except that now I get all that useless information!
Its progress whatsoever! :)

Comment: all i needed after all was the silent mode on curl "curl -s"
thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ip=$( curl -s ifconfig.co/x-real-ip ); echo -n "IP: $ip "; echo "more stuff"
```

With ip stored in variable, it is possible to avoid printing newline using the `-n` parameter.

Comment: thanks for the answer! didn't try that one but looks like its working quite good!
all i needed was the -s for silent mode!